# How to setup Authentication method policy (Preview) - Microsoft Authenticator passwordless sign-in

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have setup the "Microsoft Authenticator passwordless sign-in" for all users in the security section "Authentication methods".

But I cannot figure out how to use it in a flow?

There is an information message "Your tenant must be enabled for MFA with push notifications through the Microsoft Authenticator app in order to use this method."

How can I enable MFS in my tenant?

Has anybody got this to work yet?

regards
Stefan

Comment: If you want to know how to enable Azure MFA, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-getstarted

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD B2C only supports SMS and Phone call options for MFA.